# How to finish an activity just before starting a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains a button and it starts a Fragment when clicked.But i need to finish my current activity when starting the fragment.How is that possible?I tried calling finish() after starting Fragment.But it is not working.

```
android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
DetailFragment dialog_fragment = new DetailFragment("Events",name,id);
dialog_fragment.show(fm, "detailScreen");
finish();
```

Comment: where you tried this code??

Comment: Inside my button click event

Comment: Why not calling `finish();` before the `Fragment` ?

Comment: That is not working either.When i did that,fragment is not getting started at all

Comment: A fragment needs an activity as a container, there's no way you can "start" a fragment without an activity. I don't know your case but what you probably want to do if you're working with fragments is have an Activity that displays two (or more) fragments and in the onClick event you should replace the old fragment with the new one.

Comment: My activity is a dialog.On the button click of the dialog,i want to start the new fragment and close the dialog.This is my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getActivity().finish();` from your fragment to finish your activity.

However, be careful. Sometimes `getActivity()` could be `null`. In that case, don't call `finish()`. The activity is already destroyed.

Comment: My activity is a dialog.On the button click of the dialog,i want to start the new fragment and close the dialog.This is my scenario.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use dialog.dismiss(); after opening a fragment.